# HAVING clause in Google Sheets QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

## My Problem

I have built a count query that returns the most common elements from column H in the `final` sheet:

```
 =QUERY(final!H2:H,"SELECT H, COUNT(H) GROUP BY H ORDER BY COUNT(H) DESC")
```

I would like to filter out elements that appear only once. In traditional SQL I would add:

```
 HAVING COUNT(H)>1
```

However, this fails with `#VALUE!` on Google Sheets.

## My Question

How can I filter out query elements based on their count?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on [this Google Forum answer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/SBOoz-3Gd0s), I've nested the query:

```
=QUERY(
      QUERY(
          final!H2:H,
          "SELECT H, COUNT(H) GROUP BY H ORDER BY COUNT(H) DESC"
      ), 
      "WHERE Col2 > 1")
```

Note that the column reference in the outer query is case sensitive, and must be exactly `Col2`.